# C# How to mention List<T> size before two element join

Tags: c#, linq

See how my code. where i am joining **two datatable** and stored the result set **into `List<T>`**

```
 List<QCHelper> BogeyConfigList = null;
 BogeyConfigList = (from bogyconfiglist in Bogeylist.AsEnumerable().AsParallel() 
 join LiList in list.AsEnumerable().AsParallel()             
 on new
 {
     val = bogyconfiglist.LineItem.Trim().ToUpper(),
     val1 = bogyconfiglist.Section.Trim().ToUpper()
 }
 equals new
 {
     val = LiList.LI.Trim().ToUpper(),
     val1 = LiList.Section.Trim().ToUpper()
 }
 into conbogylist
 from confg in conbogylist.DefaultIfEmpty()
 select new QCHelper()
 {
     Section = bogyconfiglist.Section,
     Li = bogyconfiglist.LineItem,
     CrossCalc1Q = confg == null ? string.Empty : (confg.CrossCalc1Q == null ? "" : confg.CrossCalc1Q.Replace("~9999", string.Empty).Trim()),
     CrossCalc2Q = confg == null ? string.Empty : (confg.CrossCalc2Q == null ? "" : confg.CrossCalc2Q.Replace("~9999", string.Empty).Trim()),
     CrossCalc3Q = confg == null ? string.Empty : (confg.CrossCalc3Q == null ? "" : confg.CrossCalc3Q.Replace("~9999", string.Empty).Trim()),
     CrossCalc4Q = confg == null ? string.Empty : (confg.CrossCalc4Q == null ? "" : confg.CrossCalc4Q.Replace("~9999", string.Empty).Trim()),
     CrossCalcFY = confg == null ? string.Empty : (confg.CrossCalcFY == null ? "" : confg.CrossCalcFY.Replace("~9999", string.Empty).Trim()),
     AllowComma = confg == null ? false : confg.AllowComma,
     AllowedDecimalPlace = confg == null ? string.Empty : confg.AllowedDecimalPlace,
     AllowPercentageSign = confg == null ? false : confg.AllowPercentageSign,
     CurrencySign = confg == null ? string.Empty : confg.CurrencySign,
     IsQcCheck = confg == null ? false : confg.QCCheck,
     QcType = confg == null ? string.Empty : confg.QCType,
     FormulaLiConfig = confg == null ? string.Empty : (confg.StandrdFormula == null ? "" : confg.StandrdFormula.Replace("~9999", string.Empty).Trim()),
     xFundCode = bogyconfiglist.xFundCode == null ? string.Empty : bogyconfiglist.xFundCode
 }).Distinct().ToList<QCHelper>();
```

**resultset** stored into **BogeyConfigList** `List<T>` but i heard that List will have many empty items in it when data will be stored there and those empty item consume memory.

so before join how could i declare **`List<T>` with proper size** as a result join result set can fully be stored into `List<T>` ?

Please guide me how to handle this situation. i have like series of many joins in my routine where i am not able to mention `List<T>` size because i do not in advance how many data will be there after join in result set. discuss best approach to handle my scenario where i can save some memory.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can initialize `List<T>` with an initial capacity if you know what your capacity should be to save memory and make things slightly more efficient when adding items to your list by using the constructor [List<T>(int capacity)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_Collections_Generic_List_1__ctor_System_Int32_)

If you don't know what your end capacity will be, but you still want to conserve as much memory as possible you can call [TrimExcess()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.trimexcess?view=net-5.0#System_Collections_Generic_List_1_TrimExcess) after adding items to your list. This will force the capacity of your list to match the count.